# Remove XQuartz?

Tags: macos, xquartz

I installed [PlayOnMac](http://playonmac.com) to get a game to run on my computer, and it prompted me to install something called "XQuartz". It also said to log out an log back in to make it my default something. I uninstalled PlayOnMac but now I'm not sure how to get rid of XQuartz, or if I should do so at all, or remove it from whatever it became the default for.

Comment: There's a script to [Uninstall XQuartz.app from OSX Yosemite/El Capitan/Sierra](https://gist.github.com/pwnsdx/d127873e24cef159d4d603accaf37ee4) which a quick check shows matches XQuartz 2.7.11.  If you uninstall it anything that depends on the XQuartz installation won't work. If you're not aware of anything that uses it you're probably safe. You can always re-[install](https://www.xquartz.org/) it.  XQuartz was shipped with OS X 10.5 through 10.7 and a user install after that, meaning OS X/MacOS doesn't depend on it.